# Sequelize performance improvement in Version 4

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Is there any Performance improvement in Sequelize version 4 over version 3 . I used sequelize-benchmark package to check for any perceivable improvement but couldn’t find any .
I also wrote my own benchmark code and couldn’t see any performance improvements.